# блокировка в windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ноутбук

Как заблокировать ноут при закрытии крышки? Гибернация не подходит, режима сна в ноуте нету. Ноут xiaomi mi notrebook pro. Спасибо)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://techniorg.com/how-to-lock-windows-10-when-you-close-your-laptop-lid-guide/

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-my-laptop-lock-on-lid-close

Answer (score 1):

Исправил проблему обновив драйвера видеокарты, появилась вкладка сон.